# reading HTML(different folders) files

Tags: python

I want to read HTML files in python. Normaly I do it like this (and it works):

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("test.html",'r')
print f.read()
```

The Problem is that my html files are not all in the same Folder since have a program which generates this html files and save them into folders which are inside the folder where I have my script to read the files.
Summarizing, I have my script in a Folder and inside this Folder there are more Folders where the generated html files are.

Does anybody know how can I proceed?

Comment: Is there any logic to how the folders are stored that you could rely on? Would folders be nested or is everything just one level deep? Or would you have to search every subfolder for any html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import codecs

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./"):
    for name in files:
        abs_path = os.path.normpath(root + '/' + name)
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(abs_path)
        if file_ext == '.html':
            f = codecs.open(abs_path,'r')
            print f.read()
```

This will walk through `<script dir>/` (`./` will get translated to your script-directory) and loop through all files in each sub-directory.
It will check if the extension is `.html` and do the work on each `.html` file.

You would perhaps define more file endings that are "accepted" (for instance `.htm`).

Comment: @Pablo my solution gives you a list of the folders and the files, the difference is my solution is dynamic so you don't have to pre-program the names of the folders and files. I'd suggest using `os.walk` but sure, you could use 2 lists as well.

Answer (score 0):

use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os,codecs
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".html"):
             f = codecs.open(os.path.join(root, file),'r')
             print f.read()
```